# Python ошибка QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. 
Написал простой парсер:

```
import codecs #Переопределяю кодировку
def open(path, mode):
  return codecs.open(path, mode, 'utf-8')


import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # Импортирую парсер
import requests

from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QFileInfo

audioFile = r"C:\Users\Grzegorz\PycharmProjects\parser\parser\alert.mp3"
player = QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(audioFile).absoluteFilePath()))) # Для оповещения


def parser (site):
    response = requests.get(site)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")  # Выгружаю содержимое

    content = soup.find('div', {"class": "content"})

    for row in content.find_all('div', {"class": "entry"}):
            title = row.find_all('h3', {'class': "entry__title"})
            description = row.find_all('div', {"class": "entry__content"})[0].text[:-7]
            link_beta = str(row.find_all('h3', {'class': "entry__title"}))[35:]
            a = link_beta.index('"')
            link = link_beta[:a]
            photo = row.find('img', {'class': 'wp-post-image'}).attrs["src"]
            full = (photo[2:] + '\n' + ' ' + title[0].text + '\n' + ' ' + description + '\n' +
                    ' ' + link + '\n\n')

            result1 = open("fly4free.txt", "r").readlines()
            check = str(result1).find(full[:50])  # Проверяю файл на наличие спарсенного текста
            if check == -1:
                result1.insert(0, full)
                result = open("fly4free.txt", "w")
                for line in result1:
                    result.write(line)
                result.close()
                player.play()

while True:  # Псевдо-автоматизация скрипта
    parser("http://www.fly4free.pl")
    parser("http://www.fly4free.com/flights/flight-deals/europe/")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Но почему-то при запуске через cmd выдает ошибку: 
**"QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread"**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: Для того чтобы `Qt` объекты работали корректно необходимо всегда создавать `QApplication` и только после этого создавать остальные объекты. Также объекты `Qt` не будут работать если не запущен `EventLoop`. То есть у вас не будет работать обработка сообщения, пока вы не выполните метод `QApplication.exec`. При использовании Qt не получится использовать `while True` и `time.sleep`.

Comment: Avernial, я правильно понял, что в моем случае, while True, time.sleep и звуковое оповещение с Qt никак не совместить?

Comment: Да именно так. Если вы будете использовать `time.sleep` у вас все приложение будет замерзать на 5 секунд, включая проигрывание звука. Поэтому вместо time.sleep надо использовать `QTimer`. А `while True` заменится на `QApplication.exec` либо на `QCoreApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за того, что объекты `Qt` требуют `EventLoop` без которого они корректно работать не могут. Поэтому чтобы использовать эти объекти обязательно нужно создавать `QApplication` для приложения с графическим интерфейсом или `QCoreApplication` для консольного приложения. после этого необходимо вызвать метод `QApplication.exec`, который обеспечивает обработку сообщений.

Вариант как можно решить проблему:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

audioFile = "file.mp3"

app = Qt.QCoreApplication([])
player = Qt.QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(Qt.QMediaContent(Qt.QUrl.fromLocalFile(Qt.QFileInfo(audioFile).absoluteFilePath())))

timer = Qt.QTimer()


def on_timer():
    print("parse data")
    parser("http://www.fly4free.pl")
    parser("http://www.fly4free.com/flights/flight-deals/europe/")

timer.timeout.connect(on_timer)
timer.start(5000)

app.exec()
```

Comment: Avernial, огромное спасибо, все заработало!